# Can I place noneditable text in UITextField

Tags: ios

I'd like to place some fixed text inside an UITextField, but before the insert point, sort of like this:

---

### | He went (towaards)

...where "towaards" is the editable part.

The point is to show the editable text in context.

Is that possible, and/or are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can do that by implementing [`UITextFieldDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class). There is one method [– `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextFieldDelegate).

In this method you can check each and every character which is entering by user (even backspace). So first you implement change in another `NSString` object then validate with your condition.

Check whether new string passes through your validation then replace the old string with new string, otherwise leave it as it is.

For example, check new string starts with your string or not. You can use this:

`[myString hasPrefix:@"He went"];`

Here in the same method you can also do one more thing, when user taps on `UITextField` check if `@"(towaards)"` string is there in textField then remove that text by code.

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: Seems the best way to do what he asked for.

Comment: @Francesco: I guess its better to play with single UITextField then to place two objects, UILable-for static text, as well UITextField, for dynamic text. What you say?

Comment: A solution with a single object is far more elegant and flexible in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Several good selections. I ended up going a completely different route, which eliminated the need for the text input, but would probably have gone for mrunals suggestion.

Comment: @AndersSewerinJohansen: Enjoy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Just set the text property of the label to @"He went (towaards) and when editing is started change it to @"He went "

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can put noneditable and editable text in the same UITextField.

What about putting a UILabel with the noneditable text right beside the UITextField ?