# How to prevent a part of text in UITextField from being edited

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I want to keep some text in a `UITextField` from being editable. For example, I want to keep something like ".com", prepending a user's input before this ".com".

Comment: This might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248340/can-i-place-noneditable-text-in-uitextfield

Comment: Use IBAction to connect the text field to a method for changed. When it gets triggered change your text as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this method

```
(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

And using something like this inside so when the user tries to edit the last three characters, it will return NO:

```
if (string.length < 3) {
    NSLog(@"NO -> string.length < 3");
    return NO;
}
if (range.location > textField.text.length-3) {
    NSLog(@"NO");
    return NO;
}
return YES;
```

Comment: This won't work properly. If a user selects the "com" part and then taps delete, the `shouldChangeCharacters...` delegate method will be called with a zero length string. Your 1st `if` check will see this a return `YES` meaning that the selected "com" will be deleted. The opposite of what is desired.

Comment: I guess that's right, but it was just and idea of how he could work it. Anyways, I made an edition to it, and it might be less wrong now...

Answer (score 1):

When the user returns the UITextField do this:

```
 NSString *oldString = yourTextField.text;
 NSString *newString = [oldString stringByAppendingString:@".com"];
 yourTextField.text = newString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a track of each character change. If any part of ".com" is edited, restore it programatically. Make sure to give some kind of indication to the user that ".com" is not editable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like the following two ways:

```
NSString *suffixStr = @".com";
1.
NSString *newStr = [yourStr stringByAppendingString:suffixStr];
2.
NSString *newStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", yourStr, suffixStr];
```